# Java does not execute one sh file, and never ends

Tags: java, postgresql, sh

I'm trying to execute one sh file that run postgres commands, but it never ends.

The sh file is that:

```sh
 #!/bin/bash
echo "My ARGUMENTS $1 $2 $3 $4";
psql -h $1 -p $2 -U $3 -d template1 -c "drop database IF EXISTS $4";
psql -h $1 -p $2 -U $3 -d template1 -c "create database $4";
echo "OPERATION COMPLETED";
```

And my java method is the following:

```java
public void createDB() {
        try{

            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
            builder.command("sh", "-c", "ls");

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/tmp/test.sh", "localhost", "5432", "postgres", "newDB");
            Process p = pb.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERORR");
        }
}
```

the output is:

> **My ARGUMENTS localhost 5432 postgres newDB**

But never execute the second psql statement, can someone help me please.

Comment: hava you tried without the semicolons in the script? they should not be there

Comment: Try reading the error stream to see if there's anything useful there.

Comment: also, does the script work when run outside java

Comment: yes @eis, when I run outside of java it works perfectly, and also does not work without semicolons

Comment: There are no erros @tgdavies, apparently hangs

Comment: Is your process exiting? or does it just stay on forever? have you tried calling process.destroy()?

Comment: What does `ps` tell you. Is one of the `psql` processes hanging?

Comment: It's probably waiting for the password to be entered

Comment: I tried to call process.destroy() @AminM,  after the while cycle, but does not work.

Comment: debug it step by step and see what's happening.

Comment: I found the solution, It was expecting the password, and I pass it by Enviroment variable un of the process builder. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name mind adding it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soluction was the following:

```java
public void createDB() {
        try{

            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
            builder.command("sh", "-c", "ls");

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/tmp/test.sh", "localhost", "5432", "postgres", "newDB");
           // set environment variable password
            env.put("PGPASSWORD", "123456");
            Process p = pb.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERORR");
        }
}
```

I pass the password by enviroment variable. Thanks to all!